# There are $5$ apples $10$ mangoes and $15$ oranges in a basket.

Tags: permutations, combinations

There are $5$ apples $10$ mangoes and $15$ oranges in a basket. Then find number of ways of distributing $15$ fruits each to $2$ persons.

Can I approach this question as number of ways $15$ fruits from $5$ apples $10$ mangoes and $15$ oranges to one person as every time first person gets $15$ fruits, there will be $15$ fruits left in the basket.

Comment: Yes. My hint for this problem would be to choose the number of apples and the number of mangoes for one of the two people, since any combination of answers is legitimate ($5+10\le 15$.) Once you have figured those out, the rest of the distribution is "forced".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can give any combo of $0-5$ apples, $0-10$ mangoes to person $A$

Thus $6\times11 = 66$ ways (the balance needed to make $15$ will be oranges)

Comment: Thanks. That was great. Actually I also found answer too but I found it by finding coefficient of $x^{15}$ in expansion of $(1+x+..+x^5)(1+x+...+x^{10})(1+x+...+x^{15})$ which was bit lengthy.

Comment: You're welcome !

Comment: @Ananya can you post an answer describing that way? How do you proceed after that?